# Geocoding addresses including address cleaning and validation

Tags: geocoding, gis-principle, reverse-geocoding, elasticsearch

I am tasked with building a geocoder (and in the long term reverse geocoder) from a local data I own. Since I am new to this and literature is relatively scarce, I would like to know what are some best practices.

For example, my input addresses are full address strings while my data is stored by field (ex: street, city, postcode ... etc). Should I instead manipulate the data such that it is also stored as strings of addresses or should I manipulate the input address (break it down from string to fields of address components)?

I am currently using elasticsearch which I have found to be very fast and robust. Does anyone recommend anything else?

Are there any techniques or literature I can go over to validate the address before searching them in data? Since human error is very common in geocoding one has to make sure the address string is clean.

Answer (score 1):

Let me link to some blog posts I wrote about that:

- [Importing BANO dataset with Logstash](https://www.elastic.co/blog/enriching-your-postal-addresses-with-the-elastic-stack-part-1)
- [Using Logstash to lookup for addresses in BANO index](https://www.elastic.co/blog/enriching-your-postal-addresses-with-the-elastic-stack-part-2)
- [Using Logstash to enrich an existing dataset with BANO](https://www.elastic.co/blog/enriching-your-postal-addresses-with-the-elastic-stack-part-3)

I gave a demo of this during a talk recently. Here is the link to the source code I used for that: https://github.com/dadoonet/bano-elastic/

Hope this helps.

**EDIT:** In case the previous links become unavailable, here is another version of the same blog posts:

- [Importing BANO dataset with Logstash](http://david.pilato.fr/blog/2018/03/22/enriching-your-postal-addresses-with-elastic-stack-part-1/)
- [Using Logstash to lookup for addresses in BANO index](http://david.pilato.fr/blog/2018/03/24/enriching-your-postal-addresses-with-elastic-stack-part-2/)
- [Using Logstash to enrich an existing dataset with BANO](http://david.pilato.fr/blog/2018/03/24/enriching-your-postal-addresses-with-elastic-stack-part-3/)

Also here are some content extracted from those sources:

A logstash configuration to read a CSV file using filebeat (but you can replace the input part with whatever source you have):

```
input { 
  beats {
    port => 5044
  } 
}
filter {
    csv {
      separator => ","
      columns => [
        "id","number","street_name","zipcode","city","source","latitude","longitude"
      ]
      remove_field => [ "message", "host", "@timestamp", "@version", "input", "log", "ecs", "agent", "tags" ]
    }
    mutate {
      convert => { "longitude" => "float" }
      convert => { "latitude" => "float" }
    }
    mutate {
      rename => {
        "longitude" => "[location][lon]"
        "latitude" => "[location][lat]"
        "number" => "[address][number]"
        "street_name" => "[address][street_name]"
        "zipcode" => "[address][zipcode]"
        "city" => "[address][city]"
      }
    }
}
output {
    elasticsearch {
      hosts => ["http://elasticsearch:9200"]
      index => "bano"
      user => "elastic"
      password => "changeme"
      document_id => "%{[id]}"
    }
}
```

Mapping template you can use when creating the index:

```
PUT _template/bano
{
  "index_patterns": "bano*",
  "settings": {
    "index.number_of_shards": 1,
    "index.number_of_replicas": 0,
    "index.analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "bano_city_analyzer": {
          "type": "custom",
          "tokenizer": "standard",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase",
            "asciifolding"
          ]
        },
        "bano_street_analyzer": {
          "type": "custom",
          "tokenizer": "standard",
          "filter": [
            "elision",
            "lowercase",
            "asciifolding",
            "bano_synonym"
          ]
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "bano_synonym": {
          "type": "synonym",
          "synonyms": [
            "bd => boulevard",
            "av => avenue",
            "r => rue",
            "rte => route"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "address": {
        "properties": {
          "city": {
            "type": "text",
            "analyzer": "bano_city_analyzer",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword"
              }
            }
          },
          "number": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword"
              }
            }
          },
          "street_name": {
            "type": "text",
            "analyzer": "bano_street_analyzer"
          },
          "zipcode": {
            "type": "keyword"
          }
        }
      },
      "id": {
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "source": {
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "location": {
        "type": "geo_point"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Typical request to find a geo point from a postal address:

```
GET bano/_search
{
  "size": 1, 
  "query": {
    "multi_match": {
      "query": "6 allée des myrtilles cergy",
      "fields": [
        "address.city",
        "address.street_name",
        "address.number"
      ],
      "type": "most_fields"
    }
  }
}
```

Typical request to find the closest postal address (and its actual coordinates):

```
GET bano/_search
{
  "size": 1, 
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": {
        "geo_distance": {
          "distance": "1km",
          "location": {
            "lat": 49.0409,
            "lon": 2.0178
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "sort": [
    {
      "_geo_distance": {
        "location": {
          "lat": 49.0409,
          "lon": 2.0178
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/162978)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I updated the content.